# How to handle the empty function parameters?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, file

```
import re

def func1(valA="", valB="", valC=""):
     data = "Stackoverflow  Questions Answers"
     if re.match('('+valA+')\s+('+valB+')\s+('+valC+')',data):
           print "TRUE"

func1(valA="Stackoverflow", valB="Questions", valC="Answers") # This works fine
func1(valA="Stackoverflow", valB="", valC="") # This will not work, since reg-ex doesn't match
func1(valA="Stackoverflow", valB="", valC="Answers")  # This will not work, since reg-ex doesn't match
```

In second and third instance, how to manage those empty strings ?
Within the function, assigning the corresponding variable `valB=".*"`, if it's empty. is it feasible ? Because, this has to be applied for more number of parameters in large file too. `'data'` is just a line from huge file.

Comment: What do you expect from the second and third function call? true or false?

Comment: @lkdhruw: It should not return me false, it has to return me the line which contains atleast one parameter (2nd instance). It has to return me the line which has atleast those two parameters(3rd instance). If it's empty, then reg-ex fails.

Comment: Sorry, the *If it's empty, then reg-ex fails* is not quite clear. If the `valA` is `"   "`, `valB=""` and `valC=""`, then should it fail? See https://ideone.com/EBWUEZ

Answer (score 0):

The rationale is whenever a param is empty, replace it by `.*`. Try this:

```
$ cat test.py
import re

def func1(valA="", valB="", valC=""):
    pattern = ("(" +
               (valA or ".*") +
               ")\\s+(" +
               (valB or ".*") +
               ")\\s+(" +
               (valC or ".*") + ")")
    print pattern
    data = "Stackoverflow  Questions Answers"
    if re.match(pattern, data):
        print "TRUE"

func1(valA="Stackoverflow", valB="Questions", valC="Answers") # This works fine
func1(valA="Stackoverflow", valB="", valC="") # This will not work, since reg-ex doesn't match
func1(valA="Stackoverflow", valB="", valC="Answers")
func1(valA="", valB="", valC="")
```

which gives you:

```
$ python test.py
(Stackoverflow)\s+(Questions)\s+(Answers)
TRUE
(Stackoverflow)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)
TRUE
(Stackoverflow)\s+(.*)\s+(Answers)
TRUE
(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)
TRUE
```

Look at the last example: it will match the example string, even if your params have the default value.